# DateUtils getRelativeTimeSpanString always returning same Date

Tags: java, android, datetime, formatting, long-integer

Following problem:

```
Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(c.getTime()));
//c.getTime() returns a long value

    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            c.getTime(),
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS
    );

    holder.timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(timeAgo));
```

gives me the date 18th February 1970 even when my logcat gives me the correct long values:

```
CardAdapter: 1465490137 (when i calculate to date manually it is: Thu, 09 Jun 2016 16:35:37 GMT)
CardAdapter: 1465489775 
CardAdapter: 1465487453
```

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Will you try with `DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS` instead of `DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

1465490137 milli seconds is => Sun Jan 18 1970 06:34:50 GMT+0730

DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString() method will return the date string if the time different more than 7 days. It precise level seconds, minutes, hours and days less than 7 days by default.

Please refer the below link to convert the milli seconds to real date.
http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.V7U5jpN97UI